# Continuous functions from $\Bbb{N}$ to $\Bbb{N}$ in the "co-small" topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, number-theory, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

In a related post, I asked about [the "co-small" topology on $\Bbb{N}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3806575/the-co-small-topology-on-the-naturals) One of the questions was about characterizing the continuous functions from $\Bbb{N}$ to itself in this topology. Some examples of continuous functions include $f(n) = an + b$, $f(n) = \lfloor n^p \rfloor$ for $0 < p \leq 1$, the prime counting function $f(n) = \pi(n)$; some functions that are *not* continuous would be $f(n) = \lfloor \log_2(n) \rfloor + 1$, $f(n) = p_n$ (the $n$th prime), $f(n) = \lfloor e^{\sqrt{\ln n}} \rfloor$.

Other users have given partial results. [Ben shows that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3817473) if $f: \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{N}$ is continuous and $f(A)$ is small for any large set $A$, then $f$ is constant. [Greg Martin shows that](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3807677) if $f: \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{N}$ satisfies $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(n)/n = \infty$ on any large set $A$, then $f$ must map some large subset of $A$ to a small set, and therefore cannot be continuous in this topology. I think I'm prepared to give a characterization of how quickly or slowly a non-constant continuous function $f: \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{N}$ can grow:

**(Proposed) Theorem.** A function $f$ from $\Bbb{N}$ to itself is continuous in the co-small topology  <s>iff</s>  only if there exist positive constants $M, p$ such that:

1. $f(n) \leq Mn$ for all but a small set of positive integers $n$;
2. $f(n) \geq n^p$ for all but a small set of positive integers $n$.

Greg Martin's answer dispatches of (1), and Ben's answer implies that $f(n) \to \infty$ except possibly on a small set of positive integers $n$ (finite sets are small, so the preimage of any finite set under a continuous function cannot be large). My answer for the last part is based on thinking about, e.g. $f(n) = \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor$ vs. $f(n) = \lfloor \log_2(n) \rfloor + 1$.

For $f(n) = \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor$, for any integer $k$, $$\sum_{n \in f^{-1}(k)} \frac{1}{n} \approx \frac{2}{k},$$ and so the preimage of any large set is also large. This generalizes to any $\lfloor n^p \rfloor$ with $0 < p \leq 1$ as in this case $\sum_{n \in f^{-1}(k)} \frac{1}{n} \approx \frac{1}{pk}$.

OTOH, for $f(n) = \lfloor \log_2(n) \rfloor + 1$, for any integer $k$, $$\sum_{n \in f^{-1}(k)} \frac{1}{n} \approx \frac{1}{2},$$ and so any infinite set (even a small one) has large preimage.

**Question: Is it true that for any $f: \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{N}$, if $1/k = o(\sum_{n \in f^{-1}(k)} \frac{1}{n})$ on a large set of positive integers $k$, that $f$ maps a large set to a small set? And, if this is not equivalent to (2) above, what is an explicit counterexample?**

I've tried to demonstrate the equivalence above, but I'm having a hard time giving a solution in full generality. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit:** [Hanul has shown](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3822325) that the above conditions are not sufficient to establish continuity. Are they necessary?

Answer (score 2):

It could be out of your question, but your proposed theorem is false.

Consider the following function:
$$h(n)= (k+1)^k \qquad\text{if}\quad k^k\le n<(k+1)^{k+1}.$$
You can see that if $k^k\le n<(k+1)^{k+1}$, then

1. $h(n)=(k+1)^k = \left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k k^k \le en$, and
2. $h(n) = (k+1)^k \ge (k+1)^{(k+1)/2} \ge n^{1/2}$.

Consider $A=\{(k+1)^k\mid k\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Then $A$ is small, but its inverse image under $h$ is the set of all natural numbers, so $h$ is not continuous.

Comment: OK, so it's not sufficient. What about necessary?

Comment: @RiversMcForge I have no idea yet, although I believe it holds.

Comment: After mulling over your example (very clever, btw), two thoughts: 

1) It's clear that there are a ton of easy counterexamples to the original "Proposed theorem" showing lack of sufficiency, e.g. $f(n) = k^m$ for $k^m \leq n < (k+1)^m$ and any fixed positive integer $m \geq 2$.

2) Perhaps a counterexample to the lower growth bound could come in the form of some inverse function like $f(n) = k$ for $k^k \leq n < (k+1)^{(k+1)}$.